# Android activity method to get image returns null PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

i'm currently developing an android app in which the user has ability to post images which are then linked to their own profile. this project occurred as my first use of PHP for forgive me for seeming a little new to it. when they upload an image, it is passed from android studio and saved to a MySQL database via a PHP script.

PHP script is below:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT post_image FROM post_image WHERE post_image_id = '$id'";
require_once('dbConnect.php');

$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

header('content-type: image/jpeg');

echo base64_decode($result['image']);

mysqli_close($con);

}else{
echo "Error";
}
```

as you can see, this will then fetch the image from the database, pass it to android and then is displayed in an imageview, however, in android studio, the imageview is passed null and therefore nothing is displayed. having discovered this, i ran the above PHP script in my browser and discovered that it doesnt return the image either, it simply displays an empty placeholder for an image

I have based this PHP script off another similar one I have already implemented in my app which works without issue, the only difference in the two scripts being the query.

any help would be appreciated in trying to discover what the issue with this script is.

Comment: If the image is POSTed then why does the script use GET? It will echo "Error".

Comment: Moreover the php script is nowhere saving a received image to a database.

Comment: tried echo base64_decode($result['image'][0]); ?

Comment: this is the script to retrieve the image from the database, as i stated above. this is not to upload an image, an image has already been uploaded. this image is to retrieve the image which has already been uploaded in another activity

Comment: @CaolánÓDálaigh check my answer below and see it is helpful to you or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting `post_image` from table while in result you are using `image`. That is the issue. change your result data to

```
echo base64_decode($result['post_image']);
```

Keep in mind  in developing environment always keep error enable so you can easily get it. Or check error log

Comment: got it! thank you. i feel like an idiot now, having let such a simple mistake get the best of me! i appreciate the feedback

Comment: Glad to help @CaolánÓDálaigh :)